# Hard disk drive not visible in 'My computer'

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning

I have a 250 GB SATA hard disk, that was partitioned as follows:

- C: - 60 GB
- E: - 40 GB
- F: - 40 GB
- G: - 45 GB
- H: - 45 GB

However, only `C:` is visible in *My Computer* now. All other partitions are missing.

When I open the *Disk Management* window, it shows a 170 GB RAW healthy logical drive.

Can I recover my drives without losing my files?

Comment: I have 2 question: 1.Have you formatted the disk?  2. Whate are filesystem of those partition ?

Comment: Have you been messing with the disk's partition table? There is a lot of useful software that can help you rollback the changes. Take a look at this one.
http://www.partition-recovery.com/ I haven't tried it but it's freeware.

Comment: Did the drive 'go missing' in the running machine or did you move it to another machien? Had you been using any recovery/maintenance software shortly before this happened?

Comment: Is it possibly hidden?  When you open My Computer, and type "F:" in the location bar, do you see the files?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the free version of [Partition Find and Mount](http://findandmount.com/) on the drive. If it works, there's also a commercial version which is useful if you have a significant number of folders and files to recover.

If you have to create a volume on the drive first, make sure you use the Quick Format option to minimize the loss of data still on it.